# Why do I keep getting "Cypress failed to start" on step 2 of the Nx using React tutorial?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, nomachine-nx

I keep getting a "Cypress failed to start." message when trying to run e2e tests using Nx. I am new to Nx and not sure how to fix the issue. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my issue through reinstalling Cypress using the --force tag. Hope this helps if anyone else hits this issue.